# Okay to bend plastic pipe/conduit with some tension to fit the trench?

Tags: plumbing

If the trench for ABS drain pipe and PVC conduit isn't perfect, can I bend the pipe so its offset a couple of feet over about 25 feet??  Its held in place by the trench walls but under some tension.  Once its buried it won't move, but is there any problem with doing that? Also slightly 'fudging' the hub connections so its about 1 or 2 degrees from straight?

Comment: Both are quite flexible in smaller diameters, so if it doesn't take significant effort to bend it, I think you'll be ok.  I would NOT, however, fudge the connections unless you want a failure down the road.  Get fittings that match the route you need to take or dig the trench wider.

Comment: @jwh20 That's probably clear enough to be an actual answer, not just a comment.

Comment: Just glue it straight, out of the trench if need be. Let it cure, then put it in the trench. You'll be shocked just how floppy a long length of the stuff is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are quite flexible in smaller diameters, so if it doesn't take significant effort to bend it, I think you'll be ok.

I would NOT, however, fudge the connections unless you want a failure down the road. Get fittings that match the route you need to take or dig the trench wider.